# How to use nested Consumers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, nested, provider, consumer

I need to access two different view model in one page in Flutter.
How to use nested Consumers in Flutter, Will they effect each other?

How can I use it in this code for example?

```
class CounterDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CounterModel>(
      builder: (context, counterModel, child) {
        return Text('${counterModel.count}');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Consumer2<>` to access two different providers like this :

```
class CounterDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer2<CounterModel, SecondModel>(
      builder: (context, counterModel, secondModel, child) {
        return Text('${counterModel.count}');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

With this, your `Text()` widget will be rebuilt each time one the providers value is changed with `notifyListener()`.

If your `Text()` widget doesn't need to be rebuilt with one of your providers, you can simply use `Provider.of<MySecondProvider>(context, listen: false);`.

Here for example:

```
class CounterDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CounterModel>(
      builder: (context, counterModel, child) {
        MyThemeProvider myThemeProvider = Provider.of<MyThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
        return Text('${counterModel.count}', color: myThemeProvider.isDark ? Colors.white : Colors.dark);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely nest consumers, but you need to understand if you really want them to nest.

**Case 1: Nesting consumers:**

```dart
class CounterDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CounterModel>(
      builder: (context, counterModel, child) {
        return Consumer<SomeAnotherModel>(
      builder: (anothercontext,anotherCounterModel, anotherChild) {
        return Text('${counterModel.count}');
      });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that if consumer for `CounterModel` is rebuilt, everything will be rebuilt. If consumer for `SomeAnotherModel` is rebuild, only the part inside its builder would be rebuilt.

Instead of using consumers this way, I'd recommend them to be used as in case 2 below.

**Case 2: Use consumers on the required components:**

```dart
class CounterDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        children:[
        Consumer<CounterModel>(
          builder: (context, counterModel, child) { return...}),
        Consumer<CounterModel>(
          builder: (anotherContext, anotherModel, anotherChild) { return...}),
        ]
    );
  }
}
```